# flutter how to save image in clipboard?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-11

I want to save the image to the clipboard (android flutter) .

This feature is available in Android 11.How can I do this in Flutter?

I searched a lot of sources but couldn't find any.

Comment: You can save the base64 image String in the clipboard and then use it whenever you want converting the String to File again.

Comment: No, I want it to be saved in the phone's clipboard and the user can paste it anywhere using the phone's keyboard, for example in the Telegram chat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package: [pasteboard](https://pub.dev/packages/pasteboard)

```
import 'package:pasteboard/pasteboard.dart';
    
    Future<void> readAndWriteFiles() async {
      final paths = ['your_file_path'];
      await Pasteboard.writeFiles(paths);
    
      final files = await Pasteboard.files();
      print(files);
    }
    
    Future<void> readImages() async {
      final imageBytes = await Pasteboard.image;
      print(imageBytes?.length);
    }
```

Comment: dont support android! its for ios or web!

Comment: what do u mean? it supporst android linuxwindows ios and web!